# Graphics programming: When should triangles be rendered instead of lines?

Tags: opengl

I am currently studying computer graphics and OpenGL on my own. So far I know that the GPU knows the primitives point, line and triangle. I ask myself, when do I tell the GPU whether it should, for example, render a polygon with lines or triangles? A rectangle consists of four lines or two triangles. Is there a rule of thumb to help you decide when to render lines or triangles in such a case?

Comment: *A rectangle consists of four lines * - This only renders the outline of the rectangle. Line primitives are for liens or wireframes. Tringles primitives are for filled shapes. See [OpenGL wiki - Primitive](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive).

Comment: @Rabbid76 oh, I get it. So the rule of thumb is: lines for wireframes and triangles if I want filled shapes.

Comment: Yes it is. That is all specified here: [OpenGL ES Specification - Khronos OpenGL ES Registry](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_es.php)